# Javascript Zipped Arrays Automatically Indexed or Named

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

How do I zip two or more arrays and then iterate through each element by name instead of by index? In Python, you could do this:

```
for A, B in zip(As, Bs):
```

However, in Javascript I am using something like this:

```
var As = [1,2,3];
var Bs = [4,5,6];
_(As)
.zip(Bs)
.map(function(x) { 
    return {A:x[0], B:x[1]}; // I want x[0] and x[1] mapped to names.
})
.map(function(x) {
    // Now I can use x.A and x.B.
    ...
```

Is there a better way to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.object`](http://underscorejs.org/#object) to convert an array into an object :

```
_(zipped).map(function(values) {
    return _.object(['a', 'b'], values);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1quhesmq/

Or with a partially applied function if you prefer

```
_(zipped).map(_.partial(_.object, ['a', 'b']));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1quhesmq/6/

---

You could also extend Underscore to generalize this behavior, for example:

```
_.mixin({
  namedzip: function() {
    var zipped = _.zip.apply(null, _.initial(arguments, 1)),
        list = _.last(arguments);

    return _(zipped).map(function(values) {
        return _.object(list, values);
    });      
  }
});
```

and you would call

```
_(As).namedzip(Bs, ['a', 'b']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1quhesmq/5/

Comment: Your first example isn't really more concise than what I'm doing although it does get rid of indexing. Let me consider the extending option...

Comment: I'm going to give you credit for the question. This is what I ended up implementing:
`_.mixin({nameElements:function() { var list = _.first(arguments); var names = _.rest(arguments); return _(list).map(function(x) { return _.object(names, x); }); }});`